# Overriding the physical menu button on android

Tags: android, android-menu, android-keypad

I would like the menu key on my Android device to open a dialog instead of opening the menu while my app is running. I tried to code that into `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` but it worked only for the first time I pressed the menu button. Can I do it in some other way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override the default behavior of system key presses by intercepting them in your Activity. This is done by overriding the [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) event, **and returning `true` if you want to prevent the key from being handled by the system**. The code for your case should look something as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
   if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {

       // perform your desired action here

       // return 'true' to prevent further propagation of the key event
       return true;
   }

   // let the system handle all other key events
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This may not work for all keys though; the reason for this is that keys are sent to the current `view` before the `activity` receives this message. In this case you will need to override the `onKeyDown` for the current view as well.

Comment: thanks @free3dom for that great answer, hugely useful to new Android chums!  you may have the answer to this lameass follow-up... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710375  cheers again

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my activity to override the Back key, it should work the same for the Menu key:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
    // Show your menu
  } else {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```